# How to create an file on remote (linux) machine using python from window 7

Tags: linux, python

I Want to create a file name (loginconfig.xml)with some contents in the specific directory of remote (Linux) machine for example, under a desktop directory cd~/Desktop/.

I am using import telnetlib module to reach cd~/Desktop/ even i am able to create a file as well, but unfortunate to insert below content in (loginconfig.xml file)

below is my code:

```
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until(b"login: ")
tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")


file_create1=tn.write(b"touch /opt/loginConfig.xml"+ b"\n")
#go to opt directory  
next_line_come = tn.read_until(b"#")
tn.write(b"chmod 777 /opt/loginConfig.xml"+ b"\n")

next_line_come = tn.read_until(b"#")

location=tn.write(b"/opt/loginConfig.xml")

write_under_file=open(b"location","w+")

write_under_file.write('<config\n')
write_under_file.write('user="name"\n')
write_under_file.write('password="admin!"\n')
write_under_file.write('autoLogin="true"\n'
```

The file is creating not able to write content under file what should be a good way to write a file with contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `open(b"location","w+")` you are just opening a local file called 'location', not the file you created on the remote system. If you want to write to a remote file using telnet you have to issue the same kind of commands you would use in a terminal prompt: `echo "Some line" >> /remote/path/to/somefile`.

Now, it is usually a lot easier to prepare the file on the local machine and then move to the other host using a file transport protocol (FTP or else).

Comment: Thanks it' working but one problem I'm facing. unable to write below the line in python. tn.write("echo 'password="admin" ' >> /opt/login.xml".encode('ascii')+b"\n") ......getting error SyntaxError: invalid syntax